# Binding Nested User Controls to Composite View Model

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I have a very simple composite model made of two classes:

```vb
Public Class ParentModelVM
  Public Property Name As String
  Public Property ChildModel As ChildModelVM

  Public Sub New()
    Name = "A Parent Model"
    ChildModel = New ChildModelVM With {.Name = "A Child Model"}
  End Sub
End Class

Public Class ChildModelVM
  Public Property Name As String
  Public Property Description As String
End Class
```

Both implement INotifyPropertyChanged, which I have abbreviated out.  I am attempting to produce a User Control to edit a ParentModelVM:

```
<UserControl x:Class="EditParentModel" .../>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="ViewModel" />
    </UserControl.DataContext>

    <TextBox Name="NameInput" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    <local:EditChildModel x:Name="ChildModelInput" ViewModel="{Binding Path=ChildModel}"/>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel is a ParentModelVM that is registered as a DependencyProperty that binds two-way by default.  I have a similar UserControl called EditChildModel that has a ViewModel property of type ChildModelVM, also registered as a DependencyProperty that binds two-way by default.

This logic seems to make sense to me: ParentModelVM has a String that is edited with a TextBox control whose Text property is bound, and it has a ChildModelVM that is edited with an EditChildModel control whose ViewModel property is bound.

ParentModelVM.Name correctly binds to its text box, and the two ChildViewModelVM properties correctly bind to their text boxes.  However, EditParentModel.ViewModel.ChildModel is *not* the same object as EditChildModel.ViewModel, and I cannot figure out why.  The behavior of the entire application is exactly the same if I remove the `ViewModel="{Binding Path=ChildModel}"` attribute from the EditParentModel UserControl.  For example, NameInput initalizes with "A Parent Model", but EditChildModel.NameInput does not initialize with "A Child Model" like I expect.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

**--Edit--**

Ok, I've simplified this beyond absurdity, and it still doesn't work.  I have a model called SimpleParent.  This is the entire code:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class SimpleParent
  Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

  Private _someText As String
  Public Property SomeText As String
    Get
      Return _someText
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
      _someText = value
      RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("SomeText"))
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Sub New()
    SomeText = "This is some text."
  End Sub

  Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
End Class
```

I created a UserControl called "SuperTextControl" that acts exactly like a TextBox, with a DependencyProperty called "Says" instead of Text.  Here is the entire XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SuperTextControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="23" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
  </UserControl.DataContext>
  <TextBox Name="SaysInput" Text="{Binding Path=Says}" />
</UserControl>
```

And here is the codebehind:

```vb
Public Class SuperTextControl

  Public Shared ReadOnly SaysProperty As DependencyProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("Says", GetType(String), GetType(SuperTextControl))

  Public Property Says As String
    Get
      Return CTypeDynamic(Of String)(GetValue(SaysProperty))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
      SetValue(SaysProperty, value)
    End Set
  End Property

End Class
```

Then I created a SimpleParentControl, which has a SimpleParent DependencyProperty.  I have it as a DP because I might want to nest this control inside of other controls which bind to the SimpleParent property.  Here is the entire XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SimpleParentControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"             
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="SimpleParent" />
  </UserControl.DataContext>
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=SomeText}" />
    <local:SuperTextControl Says="{Binding Path=SomeText}" />
  </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

And the entire codebehind:

```vb
Public Class SimpleParentControl

  Public Shared ReadOnly SimpleParentProperty As DependencyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SimpleParent", GetType(SimpleParent), GetType(SimpleParentControl))

  Public Property SimpleParent As SimpleParent
    Get
      Return CTypeDynamic(Of SimpleParent)(GetValue(SimpleParentProperty))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As SimpleParent)
      SetValue(SimpleParentProperty, value)
    End Set
  End Property

  Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    SimpleParent = New SimpleParent()

  End Sub

End Class
```

The TextBox in SimpleParentControl displays "This is some text", as expected.  The local:SuperTextControl displays nothing.  This is the simplest example I can possibly think of of creating a reusable UserControl, and yet it doesn't work.  Surely, someone has had some success creating a re-usable UserControl as simple as a custom textbox, but no online tutorials discuss specifically how to do this.  This is an extremely trivial example that fails for seemingly no reason.  I would very much appreciate any insight into this.  Thanks.

Comment: you can use [WPFInspector](wpfinspector.codeplex.com) to see what is the `DataContext` of your `EditChildModel` user control. without this template and without code-behind its hard to say what did you missed.

Comment: Simplify your design. Don't use a DP for binding the DataContext. Set VM directly to DataContext.

Comment: @LPL - Can you explain this further?  I thought I already was setting EditChildModel.ViewModel directly to the EditParentModel control's DataContext, through the binding.  Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this [Simple Pattern for Creating Re-useable UserControls](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/02/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole problem was that I was setting my DataContext at the UserControl level, which was "peeking out" into the parent control.  Thanks to LPL for pointing me to the blog post which clarified the issue: [A Simple Pattern for Creating Re-useable UserControls in WPF / Silverlight](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html)

It has nothing to do with RelativeSource vs. ElementName vs. setting the DataContext in the codebehind; these are all different ways of accomplishing the same thing.  The problem is evident in the diagram near the bottom of that blog post.  Doing this in the child control (SuperTextControl):

```
<UserControl x:Class="SuperTextControl" ... >
  <UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
  </UserControl.DataContext>
  ...
</UserControl>
```

Is equivalent to declaring the control in the parent like this:

```
<local:SuperTextControl Says="{Binding Path=SomeText}">
  <local:SuperTextControl.DataContext>
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
  </local:SuperTextControl.DataContext>
</local:SuperTextControl>
```

It makes sense that this won't work.  My previous answer is incorrect: changing to ElementName has the same problem if the DataContext is defined in the same way.  To get around this, set up your "internal" DataContext on the outermost child of the UserControl, rather than the UserControl itself:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SuperTextControl" x:Name="SuperTextControl">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
      <Binding ElementName="SuperTextControl" />
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <TextBox Name="SaysInput" Text="{Binding Path=Says}" />
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: The link is broken. Here's the updated version. http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/02/06/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight.html

Comment: Thanks @rybo103.  I've updated the link in the answer.